# Tikiwiki login fails with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies, wiki, tiki-wiki

I installed Tikiwiki LTS version 16 on Ubuntu 14.04.
I have a problem with Google Chrome when I try to login to the wiki. 
It is a problem of dealing with cookies, I think. It passed in Firefox.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, Tikiwiki need to be runned using a virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details so you can be helped.
You are using 16.0 or 16.2 ? (last stable)
Do you see http://yourdomain/tiki-login.php on Chrome ?
When you fill the 2 fields and submit what happen ?

Comment: Hello , I tested tikiwiki 15.4 and 16.2 and i got the same error.
when i access to http://yourdomain/tiki-login.php  and i try to login using username and password then i am redirected to the login page ( it is working with firefox)

Answer (score 0):

If you can log in with Firefox check the cookie settings on the login control panel, maybe the path or something got set wrong. 
Try switching remember me off completely maybe?
Also check if sefurl is enabled, and if so try disabling that too.

The tiki.org sites all run on tiki 16.x latest and we haven't heard of any problems like this.